# Imagemagick won't run after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade

Imagemagick file conversion program won't run since upgrading to 15.04. I removed and reinstalled the program, but it still won't run.

Comment: [edit] your question and post the error message

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Rails app with Imagemagick, the RMagic gem had to be upgraded to the newest version for it to work.

The error I kept getting was something like

```
LoadError: libMagickCore.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/rails/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so
```

When upgrading to 15.04, the imagemagick dependency changed from libMagickCore.so.5 to 6-something. I uninstalled imagemagick, purged it, and then re-installed. That still didn't fix my issue, so I updated my RMagick gem (from 2.13.x to 2.15.x) which then worked.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You must all previous rmagick remove and then will be fine:

```
sudo apt-get purge graphicsmagick graphicsmagick-dbg imagemagick-common imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6-headers libmagickwand-dev graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config
gem install rmagick
```